# API Call within a while loop not writing everything to txt file

Tags: python, database, api, file, text

Full program will call on the NYT API to find articles from 1851-present. To test I limited it to just 1851, there are only four months in this this year that have issues so months 1-8 should just return blank txt files. The issue is that only November and December are being written to their files and not Sept and Oct. You need to register for a NYT API key and also make a directory called txt_holder.

```
#create a NYT api call to scrap every year and all its months into individual txt files so that I can do a sentiment analysis month by month


#imports request function
import requests
#gets the datetime so I can get the current year
import datetime

import time

API_KEY = 

def files_and_count():
  #NYT data goes back to the year 1850
  year_increment = 1850
  today = datetime.date.today()
  year = today.year

  months = 0
  
  while year_increment != 1851:
    year_increment = year_increment + 1
    
    while months != 12:
      months = months+1
      query = str(year_increment) + "/"+ str(months)
      real_file_name = str(year_increment) + "_"+ str(months)
      file_name = str('txt_holder/'+ real_file_name +'.txt')
      file = open(file_name, 'w')
      
      search(query,API_KEY,file)

    
    months = 0

#Function that takes the API query and writes them into a file
def search(query,API_KEY,file):
  #here is the url with the query and API key as values so it is more flexible
  url = f'https://api.nytimes.com/svc/archive/v1/{query}.json?api-key={API_KEY}'
  
  print(url)

  #time between each API call
  time.sleep(12)
  
  try:
    #request the url
    response = requests.get(url)
  
    #find the JSON content
    content = response.json()
  
    #for loop to go through the text the request pulled from NYT
    for item in  content["response"]["docs"]:
      #searches in the JSON for the titles of the articles
      text = item["headline"]["main"]
      #for every article title there is a newline character added to the end of it so that each title is on a new line
      file.write(text+"\n")
      
  except:
    print('failed')
  
files_and_count()
```

Heres the one that works for me thank you for helping:

```
    #imports request function
import requests
#gets the datetime so I can get the current year
import datetime

import time

API_KEY = 


def files_and_count():
  #NYT data goes back to the year 1850

  today = datetime.date.today()
  year = today.year

  for i in range(1851, year):

    for months in range(1,13):
      
      query = str(i) + "/"+ str(months)
      real_file_name = str(i) + "_"+ str(months)
      file_name = str('txt_folder/'+ real_file_name +'.txt')
      file = open(file_name, 'w')
      
      search(query,API_KEY,file)




#Function that takes the API query and writes them into a file
def search(query,API_KEY,file):
  #here is the url with the query and API key as values so it is more flexible
  url = f'https://api.nytimes.com/svc/archive/v1/{query}.json?api-key={API_KEY}'
  
  print(url)

  #time between each API call
  time.sleep(12)
  
  try:
    #request the url
    response = requests.get(url)
  
    #find the JSON content
    content = response.json()
  
    #for loop to go through the text the request pulled from NYT
    for item in  content["response"]["docs"]:
      #searches in the JSON for the titles of the articles
      text = item["headline"]["main"]
      #for every article title there is a newline character added to the end of it so that each title is on a new line
      file.write(text+"\n")
      
  except ValueError:
    print('Could not pull content from/connect to API')
  




files_and_count()
```

Comment: Your code will be simpler if you use `for year_increment in range(year, 1852):` and `for months in range(1, 13):`

Comment: Does `print(url)` show the URL for those months? If it does, then the only reason you're not getting anything is that the API isn't returning any docs for those months. You say there should be 4 months in that year, but I think you're wrong.

Comment: What, if anything, happens with the September and October files?  Are they written as blank files?  Are they not written at all?

Comment: Use `print(content)` to see what the API is actually returning.

Comment: Does the "failed" error message ever appear?

Comment: Also, after the code is finished and you go to look at the files, are you sure you're looking in the right place?  These files will be created in a subdirectory of **the current directory**.  Are you sure you know what the current directory is?

Comment: @Barmar thank you for the simpler code snippet. When I have a chance ill implement it. The print(url) is so that you can click the link in the shell to see if the url returns something in json.

Comment: @JohnGordon Oddly enough I did the print(content) and now it populates 1851_9.txt for the first time but it stops at the print(url) part for 1851_10.txt without an error code . Im editing the code on Replit so the notation is working on my end when it comes to directories, when theres a overwhelming amount of files in it I just delete the whole directory and remade it with the same name, and I can see the new txt files being created in that directory. Before I made this post the 'failed' message did appear but on occasion but it did write to the files in some instances.

Comment: I just ran the code without changing anything and it works for now? I wonder if its because I exceeded my api calls or something

Comment: I'd expect the `failed` message to be printed in those cases.

Comment: It would be really, really helpful if you printed the actual exception, instead of just printing "failed" which tells you nothing at all about the actual problem.

Comment: is `year_increment <= year`

Comment: @cardosource year_increment has been taken out entirely in favor of the code offered by Barmar but I dont believe that was the problem. I revised the code and now the error im running into is that im doing too many requests a day so ill have to either scrape slower or find someone who can increase my limit.

Comment: request limit, for example only 10 ?